# Magento 2 Oauth Integration Error

Tags: magento2, rest-api, oauth, integration

I followed [Magento Doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html) and created checklogin.php, endpoint.php, login.php and OauthClient.php.

As the doc says in checklogin.php, there is

```
$credentials = new \OAuth\Common\Consumer\Credentials($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $magentoBaseUrl);
$oAuthClient = new OauthClient($credentials);
```

When I try to activate API Integration, It is giving error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'OauthClient' not found in /public_html/magento2/checklogin.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /public_html/magento2/checklogin.php on line 22
```

Where should I place the OauthClient.php file?

Answer (score 2):

You can place the OauthClient.php along with the other three files in your application.

You just have to add the following line in your checklogin.php

```
require 'OauthClient.php';
```